# creating new DNN skin using visual studio 2015

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin, skinning

I am working with DotNetNuke and i want to create new skin using visual studio.
I have visual studio 2015 and i have installed module template for DNN, so what is the complete process to create new working skin. 
I tired creating skin(theme) in visual studio 2015 but at last i am facing an error like below
[skin could not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrJAi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using the local URL DNNDEV.me, you will need to open the CSPROJ file that my templates generate and change the URL to your local development URL.

Are you using the "latest" release of the templates (from a few weeks ago) that have a new "wizard" interface that allows you to define the URL you're using for development? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdd506ef-d5c3-4274-bf1d-9e673fb23484

The process is pretty simple

1. Setup your DNN Development environment
2. Install the Templates
3. Create a new Project, using the Theme template, in /portals/_default/Skins/ during this process you will be given the option to choose the Name Space, email address, website, and local Dev URL for your project.

If that isn't working you likely haven't completed Step 1, or you didn't configure the right path for the local Dev URL in step 3.

Chris